# Save input values between widget rebuilds with Bloc Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have a form builded with Bloc package.
There are two options with textfields in it.
Switching between option i've made also with bloc and Visibility widget.
When I choose an option widget rebuilds, name and price values deletes.

What is the best way to save this values between choosing options?

Here is my Bloc code

```
class FormBloc extends Bloc<FormEvent, MyFormState> {
  FormBloc() : super(MyFormState()) {
    on<RadioButtonFormEvent>(_setRadioButtonState);
  }

  void _setRadioButtonState(
      RadioButtonFormEvent event, Emitter<MyFormState> emit) async {
    emit(RadioButtonFormState(
      buttonIndex: event.buttonIndex,
      buttonName: event.buttonName,
    ));
  }  
}

class MyFormState {}

class RadioButtonFormState extends MyFormState {
  final int buttonIndex;
  final String buttonName;

  RadioButtonFormState({
    required this.buttonIndex,
    required this.buttonName,

  });
}

abstract class FormEvent extends Equatable {}

class RadioButtonFormEvent extends FormEvent {
  final int buttonIndex;
  final String buttonName;

  RadioButtonFormEvent({
    required this.buttonIndex,
    required this.buttonName,

  });
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [buttonIndex, buttonName,];
}
```

Here is Form code

```
class FormInput extends StatelessWidget {
  const FormInput({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final formBlocWatcher = context.watch<FormBloc>().state;

    final nameController = TextEditingController();
    final priceController = TextEditingController();
    final formOneController = TextEditingController();
    final formTwoController = TextEditingController();
    final formThreeController = TextEditingController();
    String formOptionController = '';

    bool optionOneIsActive = true;
    bool optionTwoIsActive = false;

    if (formBlocWatcher is RadioButtonFormState) {
      switch (formBlocWatcher.buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
          formOptionController = formBlocWatcher.buttonName;
          break;
        case 1:
          optionTwoIsActive = true;
          optionOneIsActive = false;
          formOptionController = formBlocWatcher.buttonName;
          break;
      }
    }

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
          top: 15,
          left: 15,
          right: 15),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: nameController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          TextField(
            controller: priceController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Price'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 15),
          OptionsWidget(),
          Visibility(
              visible: optionOneIsActive,
              child: TextField(
                controller: formOneController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Form one'),
              )),
          Visibility(
              visible: optionTwoIsActive,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: formTwoController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Form two'),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: formThreeController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Form three'),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              BlocProvider.of<ProductsListBloc>(context).add(
                AddProductEvent(
                  productName: nameController.text,
                  productPrice: int.parse(priceController.text),
                  productDescOne: formOneController.text,
                  productDescTwo: formTwoController.text,
                  productDescThree: formThreeController.text,
                  formOption: formOptionController,
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Text('Create New'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OptionsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  OptionsWidget({super.key});

  int value = 0;

  Widget CustomRadioButton(String text, int index, BuildContext context) {
    final formBloc = BlocProvider.of<FormBloc>(context);
    final blocWatch = context.watch<FormBloc>().state;

    if (blocWatch is RadioButtonFormState) {
      value = blocWatch.buttonIndex;
    }
    return OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          formBloc.add(RadioButtonFormEvent(
            buttonIndex: index,
            buttonName: text,
          ));
        },
        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          side: BorderSide(color: (value == index) ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey),
        ),
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: (value == index) ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        CustomRadioButton("option one", 0, context),
        const SizedBox(width: 15),
        CustomRadioButton("option two", 1, context),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your FormInput class should be extends from StatefulWidget, not StatelessWidget.

After this change, you should remove all TextEditingController assignments from the build() method and move them into initState().

Comment: I actually practice with Bloc and wanted to implement it in this case

Comment: BloC never guarantees that the build() method will be called only once, but the initState() method does. Please don't try to overwhelm state's life cycle with BloC. This is an anti-pattern situation. 

An example: When the focus is on any text field and the keyboard is visible, the build() method will be called again and the TextEditingController assignments will work again. Therefore, you will lose the state again.